# How to autogenerate the username with specific string?

Tags: asp.net, mysql, database

I am using asp.net2008 and MY SQL.

I want to auto-generate the value for the field username with the format as

```
"SISI001", "SISI002",
```

etc. in SQL whenever the new record is going to inserted.

How can i do it?

What can be the SQL query ?

Thanks.

Comment: you can make a function and set the value to get update like what you want...

Comment: @Rohan :: Is there any possibilities to delete any record from table?

Comment: @Rohan :: now tell me how many characters you want to get after "SISI"?

Comment: @Rohan :: Ok. Please give me 10 min. To write the function for you.

Comment: @Rohan :: I've posted the code. Please take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a column with auto increment integer data type
Then get the maximum value of that column in the table using "Max()" function and assign the value to a integer variable (let the variable be 'x').
After that

```
string userid = "SISI";
x=x+1;
string count = new string('0',6-x.ToString().length);
userid=userid+count+x.ToString();
```

Use `userid` as your `username`
Hope It Helps. Good Luck.

Comment: here is a problem with this code. On 1000000th insertion (when the max() returns a number that is greater than 999998) line `string count = new string('0',6-x.ToString().length);` will hit a error. as the expression `6-x.ToString().length` is negative.  **Error description** : 'count' must be non-negative.Parameter name: count. **Here count means** : `6-x.ToString().length`

Comment: Ya. But i am not concatenating count. I am just concatenating userid and x.

Answer (score 1):

**PLAN A>**
You need to keep a table (keys) that contains the last numeric ID generated for various entities. This case the entity is "user". So the table will contain two cols viz. entity varchar(100) and lastid int.

You can then have a function written that will receive the entity name and return the incremented ID. Use this ID concatenated with the string component "SISI" to be passed to MySQL for insertion to the database.

Following is the MySQL Table tblkeys:

```
CREATE TABLE `tblkeys` (
  `entity` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `lastid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`entity`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The MySQL Function:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION `getkey`( ps_entity VARCHAR(100)) RETURNS INT(11)
BEGIN
    DECLARE ll_lastid INT;
    UPDATE tblkeys SET lastid = lastid+1 WHERE tblkeys.entity = ps_entity;
    SELECT tblkeys.lastid INTO ll_lastid FROM tblkeys WHERE tblkeys.entity = ps_entity;
    RETURN ll_lastid;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

The sample function call:

```
SELECT getkey('user')
```

Sample Insert command:

```
insert into users(username, password) values ('SISI'+getkey('user'), '$password')
```

**Plan B>**
This way the ID will be a bit larger but will not require any extra table. Use the following SQL to get a new unique ID:

```
SELECT ROUND(NOW() + 0)
```

You can pass it as part of the insert command and concatenate it with the string component of "SISI".

Comment: I have edited my answer providing the code for the table, function and sample calls to the function. HTH.

Comment: You can write a simple ASP.NET class/function to do the same thing. Just Google it!

Answer (score 0):

I am not an `asp.net` developer but i can help you
You can do something like this...

create a sequence in your mysql database as-

```
CREATE SEQUENCE "Database_name"."SEQUENCE1" MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 001 START WITH 21 CACHE 20 NOORDER NOCYCLE ;
```

and then while inserting use this query-----

```
 insert into testing (userName) values(concat('SISI', sequence1.nextval))
```

may it help you in your doubt...

Comment: AFAIK MySQL doesnt have anything called sequence. Oracle has.

Comment: i dont know abt that ...i just tried to give OP some hint to solve the question...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE Users (
 IDs int NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1),
 USERNAME AS 'SISI' + RIGHT('000000000' + CAST(IDs as varchar(10)), 4), --//getting uniqueness of IDs field
 Address varchar(150) 
)
```

(not tested)